# How to use StreamZip with StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, reactive-streams, dart-async, rxdart

I have two stream

```
stream1
stream2
```

I can give one to `StreamBuilder` and it work. For example:

```
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: stream1,
```

But when I combine with `StreamZip` it now give error:

```
StreamZip combinedStream() {
return StreamZip(stream1, stream2]);

}

return StreamBuilder(
  stream: combinedStream,
```

How I can combine `stream1` and `stream2` and give to `StreamBuilder`?

Answer (score 2):

```
Stream<List<QuerySnapshot>> combineStream() {

  return StreamZip([stream1, stream2]);

}


return StreamBuilder(
  stream: combineStream(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {

    List<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshot = [];

    List<dynamic> querySnapshot = snapshot.data.toList();

    querySnapshot.forEach((query) {
      documentSnapshot.addAll(query.docs);
    })

  }
);
```

Your documentSnapshot now contains your combined streams

Comment: Thanks for reply! Is not simpler way with StreamZip?

Comment: I'm making use of the StreamZip in the combineStream to zip the two streams together.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Why cannot just use StreamZip alone?

Comment: I've not tried it that way. The code snippet I posted is how I'm currently using it in my project, and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StreamGroup.merge` to merge two `Stream`s into a single `Stream`:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: StreamGroup.merge(stream1, stream2),
```

Package [dart:async](https://pub.dev/packages/async)

Comment: Thanks for reply! I try this but it not update correct in UI. It only show one stream result. Maybe because it emit at wrong time?

Comment: It should emit from both streams. Maybe another stream doesn't emit due to some condition?

Comment: Kindly share `steam1` and `steam2` data so that we can know how are you creating `stream1` and `stream2` variables and what type of data passing to `merge` function. Thanks. Look forward to hear you.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
import 'package:tuple/tuple.dart';


final Stream<A> stream1;
final Stream<B> stream2;
final Stream<Tuple2<A, B>> stream = Rx.zip2(
    stream1,
    stream2,
    (A a, B b) => Tuple2(a, b),
);

StreamBuilder<Tuple2<A, B>>(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (ctx, snapshot) { ... }
);
```