# Flutter Firebase Merge Different Streams List Problem

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a combine list of streams like that;

```
var Stream1 = _firestore
      .collectionGroup("Infos")
      .where('ID', whereIn: List1)
      .snapshots();
  var Stream2 = _firestore
      .collectionGroup("Infos")
      .where('ID', whereIn: List2)
      .snapshots();
  var Stream3 = _firestore
      .collectionGroup("Infos")
      .where('ID', whereIn: List3)
      .snapshots();
  
  List<Stream<QuerySnapshot>> combineList = [Stream1, Stream2, Stream3];
```

And with this method I merge the Streams from the `combineList`;

```
var totalStreams = StreamGroup.merge(combineList);
```

When I use totalStreams in StreamBuilder, normally, all the results of the 3 merged streams should display in the StreamBuilder, but I only display the data of the last stream(Streams3) in the StreamBuilder.

Comment: I solved my problem, you can check it from this link; [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407597/flutter-firebase-merge-streams-list-with-combinelateststream-and-display-on-stre/70433919#70433919](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70407597/flutter-firebase-merge-streams-list-with-combinelateststream-and-display-on-stre)

Answer (score 0):

Use this package https://pub.dev/packages/async like below.

```
import 'package:async/async.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class InfosWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const InfosWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<InfosWidget> createState() => _InfosWidgetState();
}

class _InfosWidgetState extends State<InfosWidget> {
  late Stream<List<List<Infos>>> _myStreamInfos;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _myStreamInfos = StreamZip(
      [
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collectionGroup("Infos")
            .where("id", whereIn: ["id1", "id2"])
            .snapshots()
            .map((query) =>
                query.docs.map((map) => Infos.fromMap(map.data())).toList()),
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collectionGroup("Infos")
            .where("id", whereIn: ["id1", "id2"])
            .snapshots()
            .map((query) =>
                query.docs.map((map) => Infos.fromMap(map.data())).toList()),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<List<Infos>>>(
        stream: _myStreamInfos,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return const SizedBox();
          }
          final listInfos = <Infos>[];
          for (final info in snapshot.data!) {
            listInfos.addAll(info);
          }

          return Container();
        });
  }
}

@immutable
class Infos {
  final String id;
  final String something;

  const Infos({required this.id, required this.something});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'something': something,
    };
  }

  factory Infos.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Infos(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      something: map['something'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I cant do that because the combineList elements(number of Streams) are dynamic. So sometimes it can include 2 sometimes 1 sometimes 4 streams.

Comment: So use a for loop : " for(list in asyncsnapshot.data){
    listOfDocumentSnapshot.addAll(list);
  }" something like that.

Comment: List<QuerySnapshot> querySnapshot;

                            for (int i = 0; i < combineList.length; i++) {
                              querySnapshot.add(asyncsnapshot.data[i]);
                            }

                            List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshot = [];

                            querySnapshot.forEach((query) {
                              documentSnapshot.addAll(query.docs);
                            });

Comment: I tıried this but this is not worked. Can you look at this solution whats the problem.

Comment: Class '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'
Tried calling: [](0) I get this error.

Comment: I tried your solution manually to try if there is a problem in my for loop. I got the same error, so there is a mistake in the solution you told me.

Comment: Use streamzip like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65133075/how-to-use-streamzip-with-streambuilder

Comment: That didn't work either. This time I got this error; type 'StreamZip<QuerySnapshot<Object>>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'

Comment: Have you used one of these solutions before? I wonder if it's not happening to me or maybe there are different solution methods now (like syntax change etc.) because there has to be a solution.

Comment: I used StreamZip and it work perfectly but I switch to Rxdart https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart.

Comment: I also tried Rx and got the same error again. The problem is not in merging the streams. In Stream builder, asyncsnapshot.data can't take any list value, so I can't use asyncsnapshot.data[0] or asyncsnapshot.data.toList(). It keeps warning that '_JsonQuerySnapshot' has no such method or use. If you used it in the same way, it should logically gives you the same error.

Comment: Ok You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61893744/how-can-i-deal-with-the-firestore-wherein-limit-of-10-when-using-a-switch-stream because it's another approche to get. You are looking for the same Collection.

Comment: I did not understand what the problem in the example you posted was and how it was solved. My problem is not at the merge stage. I have trouble defining the list in the streambuilder after merging. Do you think there is a problem in the merge phase as well?

Comment: StreamGroup merge doesn't work for me. Use StreamZip like my updated answer. Or Rxdart.

Comment: I solved my problem and I uploaded the answer, if anyone is curious, you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

To merge streams, what I can suggest to you is to use rxdart’s [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html).
Every time one of the streams emits a new event, the StreamBuilder will build.
The return snapshot.data is a list of each stream's most recent element.

When any of the source stream sequences emits an item, the combiner function merges the specified Streams into one Stream sequence.

Until all Streams have emitted at least one item, the Stream will not emit.
If one of the provided streams is empty, the resulting sequence completes without emitting any items or using the combiner
function.

Here is code example:

```
StreamBuilder( 
stream: CombineLatestStream.list([ 
  stream0, 
  stream1, 
]), 
builder: (context, snapshot) { 
  final data0 = snapshot.data[0]; 
  final data1 = snapshot.data[1]; 
})
```

Another constructor that could probably help you to merge streams is: [Merge.](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/merge.html)

The specified streams' elements are flattened into a single Stream sequence.
If one or more of the specified streams are empty, the resulting sequence completes without emitting any items.

Example code:

```
static Stream<T> merge<T>(Iterable<Stream<T>> streams) =>
    MergeStream<T>(streams);
```

Here is a [link](https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) that shows diagrams of how each constructor works.

Comment: I solved the problem, you can check my answer if you want.

Comment: Good to know that you found the solution, I saw that you used combineLatestStream, please let me know if my answer helped you to resolve your problem.
Also, I suggest you to update this current question and add the link where you upload the solution.

Comment: Only after solving the problem was I able to see that you suggested a similar method. But it's a close solution to my problem.

Comment: In the comment section, I added the link where I explained the answer to my problem, I don't know how else I can update the question.